# Integer Overflow in function

Tags: c#, math

I wrote this code -

```
public void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(b(2,4));
}

public long a(long x, long y)
{
    long result = 1;
    
    for(long i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        result = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(x,result));
    }
    
    return result;
}

public long b(long x, long y)
{
    long result = 1;
    
    for(long i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        result = Convert.ToInt64(a(x,result));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

to follow the pattern

> 2 * 3 = 2 + 2 + 2
>
> 2 ^ 3 = 2 * 2 * 2
>
> a(2,3) = 2 ^ 2 ^ 2
>
> b(2,3) = a(2,a(2,a(2,1)))

but when I add try to run this b function it gives integer overflow error.
Even though I used long, is there any way to store integers larger than long?

Comment: Consider tagging more than math. Your programming language for example.

Comment: a(2,a(2,a(2,1))) that would be a(2,a(2,2))==a(2,2^2)==a(2,4)=2^2^2^2=256. Correct?

Comment: So b(2,4) would be a(2,256). That is 2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2.... Which is 256^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2.... Better read up on "bigint".

Answer (score 0):

longs are 64 bits long, so you can store numbers up to 2^63 - 1 (because there are also negative numbers and the number 0), there is one type that can store numbers
even bigger -> ulong, but it's not that much better - 2^64 - 1

your number is equal to:
b(2,4) = a(2,a(2,a(2,(2,1)))) = a(2,a(2,a(2,2))) = a(2,a(2,4)) = a(2,256)
a(2,256) = a(256,2) <- you can write the couples of 2s in parenteces like (2^2)^(2^2)
which is 4^4 = a(4,2) and if you group them even more you'll eventually get 256^256

256^256 = 2^2048

So you would need a 2048 bits long type. The actual way to store numbers that large is some kind of array. You could write your own implementation, but I'd recommend using something premade like that https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class